# Joining multiple DateTime columns into one Columns (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, typeerror, keyerror

I am trying to gather all my date time infromation into only one columns. Right now I have a columns for each period over the span of 6 months , however in order to do a Time series Analysis , I was trying to gather all the date time into a single columns.

Here is what I tired:

```
 df['Dates'] = df["1 Month Date"]+ df["2 Month Date"]+ df["3 Month Date"] + df["4 Month Date"] + df["5 Month Date"] +df["6 Month Date"]
```

Error message :

```
  TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray
```

Second trial :

```
Dates = df["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]
```

Error Message:

```
KeyError: ('1 Month Date', '2 Month Date', '3 Month Date', '4 Month Date', '5 Month Date', '6 Month Date')
```

Extra infromation: It is an excel sheet that I imported using panda , my 1 Month date 2 Month date ect .. is a datetime64[ns]  when I do df.info())

Sample data :

```
   1 Month Date  1 Month Room Booked 2 Month Date  2 Month Room Booked  \
0    2020-09-01                  339   2020-10-01                  346   
1    2020-09-01                    2   2020-10-01                    4   
2    2020-09-01                    4   2020-10-01                    4   
3    2020-09-01                    0   2020-10-01                    0   
4    2020-09-01                    0   2020-10-01                    0   
5    2020-09-01                    1   2020-10-01                    1   
6    2020-09-01                    2   2020-10-01                    2   
7    2020-09-01                   50   2020-10-01                   58   
8    2020-09-01                   12   2020-10-01                   12   
9    2020-09-01                    9   2020-10-01                    9   
10   2020-09-01                    6   2020-10-01                    6   
11   2021-03-01                  112   2021-04-01                  112   
12   2021-03-01                    0   2021-04-01                    0   
13   2021-02-01                   36   2021-03-01                   36   
14   2021-02-01                   18   2021-03-01                   18   
15   2021-02-01                   20   2021-03-01                   20   
16   2021-02-01                   12   2021-03-01                   12   
17   2021-02-01                    0   2021-03-01                    0
```

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ? Also do you use last pandas version?

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment , df.info tells you what type of data you have so mine is a datetime64[ns], and I think so , how could it affect what I am trying to do ? How to check ?

Comment: Expected output should be 2 columns?

Comment: No there are 6 colums such as 1 Month Date , 2 Month date until 6 , and I am trying to gather all those 6 month date into only 1 colums of all the dates

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
Dates = df[["1 Month Date","2 Month Date","3 Month Date","4 Month Date","5 Month Date","6 Month Date"]].apply(pd.Series.explode).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: But when I do print(df.Dates) it says : AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Dates'

Comment: @XIUJY1111 - Can you create small data sample for see how looks data? e.g. 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: And when I do print(dates) 
It shows me this (below) that I can't use for my Time series analysis 
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
13    0.0
14    0.0
15    0.0
16    0.0
17    0.0
18    0.0
19    0.0
20    0.0
21    0.0
22    0.0
23    0.0
24    0.0
Let me know what you think

Comment: @XIUJY1111 - Honestly if error `TypeError: cannot add DatetimeArray and DatetimeArray` it seems some list data, but I need small data sample with same error. Is possible create it and add to question?

Comment: Hey I added some sample example of the data